# Union clause in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can we perform `Union` operation on multiple tables in android sqlite using `SQLiteQueryBuilder` class?

Comment: Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` (if you want to allow duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [`buildUnionQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildUnionQuery(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). From the documentation, it looks pretty straightforward, you just need to construct the individual `SELECT` statements yourself.

There is also this method [`buildUnionSubQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildUnionSubQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but i have absolutely no idea how to use it and the documentation is not very helpful...

I actually prefer a library called [SquiDB](https://github.com/yahoo/squidb), which has much better query building capabilities with an API that is more clear. (There are other libraries out there with good APIs as well. The point is you aren't stuck with using Android's `SQLiteQueryBuilder`, whose API is somewhat lacking in my opinion.)

Comment: Would you please give me a detailed example how to use buildUnionQuery()?.

Comment: @ShaheerPalollathil No, because I've never used it. But the documentation suggests i will take the array of `SELECT` statements, combine them with `UNION`s in between, and apply the `sortOrder` and ` limit` at the end. Perhaps you can give it a try and let us know.